# I wanted to search for a keyword/string "error" in a file. What is command

Tags: command-line

I wanted to search for a keyword/string "error" in a file

Answer (score 0):

Read `man grep` and do

```
grep "error" file
```

Also, please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting